# Using Webform page in Classic ASP website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic, webforms

I am updating some functionality in a classic asp website and basically to make populating a drop down happen after a value is selected in another drop down I am trying to change that page for a webform page with code behind. However, for some reason I just get the following message when attempting to go to that page:

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Is it possible to have the webform in this site? Is the issue something to do with IIS or caching? I don't actually have access to the server to refresh the IIS or anything so some clues about what could be happening would be useful before I go any further.

Thanks.

Comment: Classic asp and webforms are 2 different technologies. What are you using? And please supply some code examples!

Comment: I know, the question was basically can I use an ASPX page in an ASP website. I talked to someone about it and it is possible but it is more trouble than it is worth. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please remember this: **CLASSIC-ASP IS NOT ASP.NET**, i must retire from the don't tag asp.net questions as asp-classic office. I'm really sick of this happening very often

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just talked to someone about this and it is possible to run a webforms page in a classic asp site but the site I am working on uses a lot of session variables which are not transferred between the asp and aspx pages so it is not going to be a viable option anyway. I am going to use ajax to populate the select list.

Thanks.

Comment: You could save the session variables in a database and pass sessionid. This way u can share session data between ASP Classic and .NET. [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx)

Comment: I did think about that but it would have been more work than populating the select list with ajax. Thanks anyway.